# How to compute the number e to arbitrary precision in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, precision

Hi I want to evaluate the number e to arbitrary precision using python3. I am trying the numpy's built-in function in the following way

```
import numpy as np
print(np.exp(1))
```

which returns 2.71828182846. How can I increase the number of digits?

Comment: I am quite sure thats a constant in python, not implemented as "computation" for on the fly basis. You are not computing anything here.

Comment: Have a look at this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30105063/7505395   for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104929/where-in-the-numpy-source-code-are-the-constants-defined - `#define NPY_E         2.718281828459045235360287471352662498`