# How can I find the implementation of numpy.nan

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, nan, ieee-754

How can I find the source code of `numpy.nan` (the way it was implemented)? I tried looking using the references pycharm provides, and looked inside the [github of numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy), but got lost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where in the Numpy source code are the constants defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104929/where-in-the-numpy-source-code-are-the-constants-defined)

Comment: @AskoldIlvento Almost, How can I see the source of `__npy_nanf()` ? Because I see the definition is `#define NPY_NAN ((npy_double)NPY_NANF)` and this is defined using `#define NPY_NANF __npy_nanf()`. I want to see all the logic of how for example NaN comparison is implemented

Comment: In `numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_math.h`, it returns `0x7fc00000UL`. The comparison is implemented by hardware.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento then how does python/c know how to treat `nan`? if for example I use `nan>=5` how does it know it should return `False`?

Comment: @AskoldIlvento Ok I see, is there any documentation of that hardware implementation?

Comment: There are open standards for how hardware logic should treat nan's, like 754 pointed by Gulzar. But I'm not aware of any document describing the exact CPU schematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Numpy's `nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html) is actually implemented as the hardware floating point's `nan`.
See [Wikipedia - NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), [IEEE-754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Thus, you will not find it on Github, as it is not implemented in software.

Comment: but doesn't python need to tell you how to treat `NaN`?

Comment: and also, according to a comment on the post, numpy does implement `nan` (`#define NPY_NAN ((npy_double)NPY_NANF)`)

Comment: @ArielYael this is not an *implementation* per se, it is a constant number of some bit-configuration defined in IEEE-754. comparisons to that value or arithmatic with that value are implemented in hardware by Intel, AMD, ARM, Apple, NVidia or others, and I believe it will be hard to find the exact schematics. Question is *why* you need this and the IEEE standard is not enough?

Comment: Curiosity :)    But if the implementation can't be found the IEEE will do. thank you

Comment: @ArielYael [a bit more info](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0439/b/Floating-Point-Unit/FPU-Functional-Description/IEEE-754-standard-implementation-choices)